# Click event for a Button Array

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, button

I have a Button array in C# WFA and I want to create an event for a click of any button in the array.
How can I do it?
And how to know which location in the array it is?
I know sender is the button itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop that closes over a variable containing the current index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
{
    //it's important to have this; closing over the loop variable would be bad
    int index = i;  
    buttons[i].Click += (sender, args) => SomeMethod(buttons[index], index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I just want to know, what is the last row?
I know what its doing, just want to know how does it called so i can learn it.

Comment: It is creating an anonymous method; this particular syntax is called a lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the event handler to each button in a for loop.

Inside the handler, you can call `array.IndexOf((Button)sender)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Button[] myButtons = new Button[10];
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < myButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                int index = i;
                this.myButtons[i] = new Button();

                this.myButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(((i + 1) * 70), 100 + ((i + 10) * 5));
                this.myButtons[i].Name = "button" + (index + 1);
                this.myButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 23);
                this.myButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
                this.myButtons[i].Text = "button" + (index + 1);
                this.myButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.myButtons[i].Visible = true;

                myButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.Display(index+1);

                this.Controls.Add(myButtons[i]);
            }
        }

        public void Display(int i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button No " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This would not compile.  `Display` is not of the proper syntax, and you're invoking the method in the `for` loop, not creating a delegate from it.

Comment: how do I add an image to the button this method worked for me, and I am now trying to add an image